# How can i draw a trail/trace after a moving line?

Tags: c#, winforms

My code is drawing a circle then a line from the middle of the circle to the radius size of the circle and the line is moving by 1 angle.

Now i want to make that the line will leave some trail/trace after it like a radar effect.

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            anglecounter += 1;
            double x = pictureBox1.Size.Width / 2 + 256 *Math.Cos(anglecounter * Math.PI / 180);
            double y = pictureBox1.Size.Height / 2 +256 * Math.Sin(anglecounter * Math.PI / 180);
            CloudEnteringAlert.Paint(e.Graphics, factor, distance);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(
            new Pen(Color.Red, 2f),
            new Point(pictureBox1.Size.Width / 2, pictureBox1.Size.Height/2),
            new Point((int)x, (int)y));

            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(
                new Pen(Color.Red, 2f),
                0, 0, pictureBox1.Size.Width, pictureBox1.Size.Height);
        }
```

How can I do this?

EDIT**

This is what i did now in the top of the form i added:

```
PointF _pt = new PointF(0F, 0F);
PointF _pt2 = new PointF(1F, 1F);
PointF _pt3 = new PointF(2F, 2F);
Color _lineColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0);
private double anglecounter1;
```

Then the paint event is now look like this:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            anglecounter += 1;
            anglecounter1 += 0.5;
            double x = pictureBox1.Size.Width / 2 + 256 *Math.Cos(anglecounter * Math.PI / 180);
            double y = pictureBox1.Size.Height / 2 +256 * Math.Sin(anglecounter * Math.PI / 180);
            double x1 = pictureBox1.Size.Width / 2 + 256 * Math.Cos(anglecounter1 * Math.PI / 180);
            double y1 = pictureBox1.Size.Height / 2 + 256 * Math.Sin(anglecounter1 * Math.PI / 180);
            CloudEnteringAlert.Paint(e.Graphics, factor, distance);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(
            new Pen(Color.Red, 2f),
            new Point(pictureBox1.Size.Width / 2, pictureBox1.Size.Height/2),
            new Point((int)x, (int)y));

            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(
                new Pen(Color.Red, 2f),
                0, 0, pictureBox1.Size.Width, pictureBox1.Size.Height);

            // create the fade path and gradient
            GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath(FillMode.Winding);
            gp.AddLine(new PointF((float)(pictureBox1.Size.Width / 2), (float)(pictureBox1.Size.Height / 2)),new PointF( (float)x1,(float)y1));
            gp.AddCurve(new PointF[] { _pt2, _pt3, _pt });
            gp.AddLine(new PointF((float)x, (float)y), new PointF((float)(pictureBox1.Size.Width / 2), (float)(pictureBox1.Size.Height / 2)));
            PathGradientBrush pgb = new PathGradientBrush(gp);
            pgb.CenterPoint = new PointF((float)x1, (float)y1);
            pgb.CenterColor = Color.FromArgb(128, _lineColor);
            pgb.SurroundColors = new Color[] { Color.Empty };
            // draw the fade path
            e.Graphics.FillPath(pgb, gp);
        }
```

But if im not wrong in this case the trail/trace is slower then the line is getting faster then it. Also the trail/trace is also behind the line but also in front of the line . Im not sure but thats what i see. So what is wrong ?

Comment: Instead of drawing one radius, draw two with only slightly different angles. Paint the one with the smaller angle a little bit fainter  than the other. The human eye will do the rest.

Comment: Maybe start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fswd1t7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: create a pie slice object (maybe an arc + triangle) and fill it with a gradient that changes the alpha channel

Comment: Edited my question once again now with updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to not erase the image each time. Instead, draw a semi-transparent circle over the previous image:

```
// Initialize some dimensions
int x = pictureBox1.Bounds.X;
int y = pictureBox1.Bounds.Y;
int w = Math.Min(pictureBox1.Bounds.Width, pictureBox1.Bounds.Height);
int h = w;    // Force square
int centerX = w / 2;
int centerY = h / 2;
float radius = w - centerX;
Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
// First time draw a solid background then
// each successive time cover with semi-transparent background
Brush backGround = firstTime ? new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0)) : new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(10, 0, 0, 0));
firstTime = false;
g.FillEllipse(backGround, 0, 0, w, h);
float lineX = (float)(centerX + (radius * Math.Sin(anglecounter * (Math.PI / 180))));
float lineY = (float)(centerX + (radius * Math.Cos(anglecounter * (Math.PI / 180))));
anglecounter -= 1;
g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Green, 3), centerX, centerY, lineX, lineY);
g.DrawArc(new Pen(Color.Red, 4), new Rectangle(0, 0, w - 1, h - 1), 0, 360);
```

Produces this result:
[image]